# Is there any tool or npm package for finding out NodeJS memory leaks?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, memory-leaks, sequelize.js, mean-stack

I am looking for any tool or npm package like memwatch-next to find out NodeJS memory leak.

I observed that there are memory growth on my production server in NodeJS application. My AWS EC2 instance suddenly stops working after rebooting instance everything goes fine. After some timespan ec2 instance again stops. I have doubt that NodeJS application is consuming memory.

We are using MEAN stack (Mysql, Express, AngularJS, Node). SequalizeJS as ORM.

To dubug the issue I have used chrome debugger tool. 
Also tried to install [memwatch-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch-next) but it can't be install on ubuntu 16. NodeJS version v11.10.0. It does'nt helps in finding out memory leak.

I want npm package which will give memory leak information in NodeJS.

Is there any package available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

- [easy profiling](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/)
- [Heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump)
- [Strongloop](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-heap-snapshots/)

Here is a good blog for track & fix memory leak:

https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/04/03/how-to-track-and-fix-memory-leak-with-nodejs.html